# Problema al eliminar una fila en un jqueryDatatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Cargo datos en una tabla en un [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables), cuando elimino una fila después de usar un evento que esta colocado en una etiqueta de la siguiente manera "`<a onclick='eliminar()'></a>`", queda activado este método y se elimina con solo darle un click en cualquier parte de la fila, puedo notar que si agrego un `console.log()` dentro de la función que utilizo para eliminar la fila, este me imprime varias veces dependiendo de la cantidad de clics que he dado sobre las filas, el código es el siguiente:

```
$(function(){
    cargarDatos();
});
// Cargo los datos en la tabla
//
function cargarDatos(){
    var t = $("#luminariasAuditar").DataTable();
   for (var i = 0; i < luminaria.length; i++) {
     t.row.add([
       luminaria[i].color,
       luminaria[i].value,
       '<a href="#?" onclick=\'eliminar();\' >X</a>'
     ]).draw(false);

   }
}
// función con la que elimino las filas 
//
function eliminar () {
  var t = $("#luminariasAuditar").DataTable();
  $('#luminariasAuditar tbody tr').on('click', function (event) {
    console.log("clics");
    t.row(this).remove().draw();
  });
};
```

[Ejemplo funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/AIf4/v3z9ox2j/)

La intención, es eliminar la fila solo cuando se de clic en la "**X**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la forma con la que asignas el evento (`onclick`), es necesario pasar de alguna forma una referencia al botón (o enlace) en el que se hizo click.

Luego de ello, obtienes tal parámetro en tu función y eliminas directamente la fila. Actualmente lo que estás haciendo es agregar otro evento al evento `click` de cada fila, agregando un evento cada vez que se hace click (y, con ello, haciendo que se eliminen más de un `<tr>`).

Aquí te dejo un snippet ejecutable con los cambios que se deberían hacer.

```js
$(function() {
  cargarDatos();
});

function cargarDatos() {
  var t = $("#luminariasAuditar").DataTable();
  for (var i = 0; i < luminaria.length; i++) {
    t.row.add([
      luminaria[i].color,
      luminaria[i].value,
      // agregar "this" aquí
      '<a href="#?" onclick=\'eliminar(this);\' >X</a>'
    ]).draw(false);
  }
}

function eliminar(boton) {
  // "boton" es el <a> que se hizo clic
  var t = $("#luminariasAuditar").DataTable();
  
  // https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()
  // $().parents() obtiene el <tr> padre
  t.row($(boton).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
};

var luminaria = [{
  color: "red",
  value: "#f00"
}, {
  color: "green",
  value: "#0f0"
}, {
  color: "blue",
  value: "#00f"
}, {
  color: "cyan",
  value: "#0ff"
}, {
  color: "magenta",
  value: "#f0f"
}, {
  color: "yellow",
  value: "#ff0"
}, {
  color: "black",
  value: "#000"
}];
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="luminariasAuditar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Numero serie</th>
      <th>Dirección</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Genial @BryanHorna me funciono prefecto, Muchas gracias